# Time evolution of a composite system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information

can anyone give me a hand in order to calculate the time evolution of a composite system consisting of two subsystems. I tried many different ways but I was not able to obtain the right answer. The system is a battery and a charger which are a two level system. By the way, The Hamiltonian of our systems is:

$$ \widehat{H} = \frac{\omega_{0} }{2}\sigma{_{z}^{A}} + \frac{\omega_{0} }{2}\sigma{_{z}^{B}} + \kappa(\sigma{_{+}^{A}}\sigma{_{-}^{B}} + \sigma{_{-}^{A}}\sigma{_{+}^{B}}) $$

$`\kappa`$ is the coupling constant between the battery and charger. now if we consider the initial state of the system as:

$$ | \psi_{(0)} \rangle = | e , g \rangle $$
which in here $ | e \rangle_{A}\bigotimes | g \rangle_{g} $, "A" represents the charger and "B" is the battery.
as we can see in here we have considered the system as closed quantum system. therefore we can have the evolution of the system using unitary operators:
$$ | \psi_{(t)} \rangle = U | \psi_{(0)} \rangle $$

and U for a time independent Hamiltonian is :

$$ U = e^{\frac{-i}{h}\widehat{H}t} $$

in this situation if we effect the U on energy eigen basis we are able to replace the H with energy eigen values. I know how to do this operation for a singular system but I can not use the same way for a composite system which is :

$$ | \psi_{(t)} \rangle = e^{\frac{-i}{h}({\frac{\omega_{0} }{2}\sigma{_{z}^{A}} + \frac{\omega_{0} }{2}\sigma{_{z}^{B}} + \kappa(\sigma{_{+}^{A}}\sigma{_{-}^{B}} + \sigma{_{-}^{A}}\sigma{_{+}^{B}}))} t} | \psi_{(0)} \rangle $$

I will be so thankful if anyone can lend me hand to overcome this.

Comment: Your states $|a,b\rangle$, where $a,b \in \{g,e\}$ are not eigenstates of the total Hamilton operator. Your Hilbertspace is four-dimensional, so you have to diagonalize a 4x4 Hamiltonian. Just look up how the tensor product of two 2x2 matrices looks like, then you can write out the total Hamiltonian as a mtrix and diagonalize it. Then time evolution is trivial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are many different ways to solve these types of time evolution. You can try to straight-up use the Schrödinger equation, you can diagonalize the Hamiltonian (since it's just a $4\times 4$ matrix) or, the way I prefer for simple systems like this just plug it into whatever programming language you like. See this Mathematica code with the answer, where the Time evolution operator matrix is obtained:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your passion to answer all my questions. It seems like I have to learn Mathematica. It sounds very useful.